# jonkyking/SlideMenu 'attempt to push a View Controller ..its navigationController == nil'

Tags: ios, swift, slide

Swift 4

I'm using the fantastic resource [jonkyking/SlideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu), but I need a little help implementing it.  SlideMenu comes up fine in my MapViewController.  If user clicks on a UIButton in the TableViewController (of SlideMenu) they are supposed to  segue to LocationViewDetailController. But I get ..

> SideMenu Warning: attempt to push a View Controller from Optional() where its navigationController == nil. It must be embedded in a Navigation Controller for this to work.

I'm confused since I assume making use of SlideMenu would mean that MapViewController would not be embedded in a Navigation controller since SlideMenu is a NavigationViewController + TableViewController.

[You can see my git repo here](https://github.com/bbookman/BMap/tree/mapUI)

Perhaps this is question #2, I'm wondering how to have this SlideMenu follow to other view controllers (such as LocationViewController above). **If you have successfully implemented SlideMenu, please tell me how to keep the same menu and get it on other view controllers, the SlideMenu demo app is not helping me** . Do you have a repo I can look at or a tutorial?  Thanks

Comment: If you use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), you can use [this](https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the issues pane on the library you use on gitHub, I saw that there are couple other people having similar issues and they've posted their solution for it.  They basically embedded the `UIViewController` that invoked the side menu into a `UINavigationController`. The issue reported on github is marked closed and it's #255

Comment: let me check it out.  i can't believe i didn't check